# Excel VBA script detects value in cell, causes sheet to blink until clicked on

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a dashboard that users will be copy and pasting a log into. The dashboard will do some analysis on the data on several sheets with formulas only.

I would like to set up a VBA script that, when a formula comes out to TRUE in B25, that the sheet will blank back and fourth from green to red until the user clicks on the sheet tab and end the loop. I'm very new to VBA and scraped some code from a macro to make an attempt. Here is what I have:

```
Sub Test()

If Range("B25").Value = "TRUE" Then

Do Until Sheets("Dilutions").Activate

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dilutions").Tab
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With

Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dilutions").Tab
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
End With

Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
Loop
End If
End Sub
```

When running the script where TRUE is found in B25 the sheet tab does not change colors. I don't get any error messages with my code, so I'm at a loss at where to start troubleshooting. I have made sure that I do not have the "Dilutions" sheet selected when testing the macro and that B25 does evaluate to true.

Any help on this would be most welcome. I will continue to play with this / if I find out the solution I will follow up. Thank you!

Comment: You probably need a Calculate Event macro to detect the result of the **B25** formulas actions and some `OnTime` macros to control the blinking.

Answer (score 0):

You may run into further issues down the road with these requirements, but a good start is to work from your Worksheet's Change event.

In your VBE, go to your worksheet that contains the cell you are tracking and drop down the box at the top of the code to select "Worksheet", then drop down the box to the left and choose "Change".

This will create a new subroutine in that worksheet's VBA code called `Worksheet_Change()`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

This has a parameter called `Target` that is loaded by default with `Range` that had the `change` that caused this subroutine to fire. To detect which cell it was you can use `INTERSECT`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B25")) Is Nothing Then
          If Target.Value = "True" Then Call Test
     End if
End Sub
```

So here we detect which cell changed, and then we call the test subroutine if it's `B25` and the value is `True`.

In your `Test()` subroutine, you can take out lines that reference `B25` since we are doing the detecting here in the `Worksheet_Change()` event subroutine.

Once you get that squared away, the `Application.OnTime` method will allow you to set up a schedule where a macro is called (say 1 second from current time) and then that macro will toggle the color, but that's the next hurdle. The first is getting this thing triggered from a worksheet change.